# A Cool, Witty name for NetworkEngineering

Tags: discussion

I'm probably just dreaming, but... Given that the flagship sites have amusing names (i.e. Stack Overflow, Server Fault) - perhaps we could eventually attain something similar?

Here's a few of my ideas that I'll throw out there:

- Network Unreachable (as in the ICMP Destination Unreachable code)
- Packet Loss
- Bridge Storm
- Routing Loop

Comment: i love Network Unreachable especially when  you come to stack over flow when something is wrong - like an overflow ...

Comment: Many of the questions are not specific issues that need to be solved, but design, planning and general knowledge questions.

Comment: What about: Static Route

Answer (score 7):

Personally I think the obvious name being used right now is a good way to attract a larger user base, which I think should be the primary goal right now to make this site a success. I like some of the suggestions though, especially 'network unreachable'.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think changing is a good idea. The name was selected during the proposal stage back in Area51.

Answer (score 3):

Jeez, it looks like I'm the only one that thinks Packet Loss was the best name.  Where do you go when you're at a loss for an answer?  Packe Loss.

Comment: Packet Loss is a winner for me, too.

Answer (score 1):

Network Engineering aka Network Unreachable!  Maybe we stick with the current name and once we're out of Beta propose a vote?

Answer (score 0):

What about "PacketSniffer"? Since we are sniffing around in the world of packets... :)