# Name for the chatroom

Tags: discussion

Since the consensus at the moment seems to not change the name of the website, maybe we can reuse the proposed names  in [A Cool, Witty name for NetworkEngineering](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109/a-cool-witty-name-for-networkengineering)
to give our main chatroom a name?

Answer (score 4):

"Collision Domain"

...and more chars for min length :^D

Answer (score 4):

Network Engineering Meet-Me-Room (MMR).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meet-me-room

Comment: @Robert Cartaino, new visitors to the chat room who don't know the double meaning of MMR would think the meet-me-room is where they go to first meet in chat.

Comment: this is brilliant :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can create further chat rooms with very fancy names. I think it's good to have a main chat room with a name matching the site name. It's easier to find us, and it reduces the pressure to be cool and witty in the chat, such as when I want to talk a bit more seriously about the site and the topics.

Still it's hopefully fun there! We can start some fun with a *room description* which is less dominant but can be nice eye-catcher. Such as here, still with the generic beta theme.

[image: chat room]

Comment: Well said. I'm totally stealing this argument. *grin*

Answer (score 2):

I like "Layer 8".  It's something that networkers might find amusing, and it typically refers to people.

Answer (score 1):

Why not the **"Network Engineering Chat Room"?**

I never quite understood the desire to obfuscate what your chat room is about behind a clever name. The meta folks here get a bit of a chuckle; maybe a pat on the back… and then you've lost your chat room among a list of obscure names and insider jokes. I don't get it.

It just seems like a lost opportunity to attract an audience.

Comment: Well if they click chat on this page it will still be the first room to show