# Why I can't I upload a png or jpg image?

Tags: bug

Here on the meta site, I posted an answer to: [Name for the chatroom](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/name-for-the-chatroom).

When tried to upload an image, using the Internet Explorer 8, I got, both for png and jpg format, the error message:

> Failed to upload; not a valid image (jpeg, png, tiff, gif or bmp)

However, uploading from the web worked. Is it a bug, or might be requirements not matched? The image was 9 kb in size and saved in a format matching the file name extension. Now I noticed the same on the main site.

Screenshot, uploaded via a web site, since this did not work either:

[image]

Finally, I tested with Mozilla Firefox 20.0.1, that was working. However, I still wanted to post this question, perhaps somebody noticed the same issue with another browser or version, and it may be relevant for beta sites in general.

Comment: IE 8 is not a supported browser. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208